# Ubuntu (WSL): How should I be setting these paths for Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, meteor

I recently installed Android Studio on Ubuntu (WSL) for my Meteor project but it installed to `/opt/android-studio`.  I see that the `SDK` is installed to `/root/Android/Sdk`.  I've added it to the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` env variable but it says its a non existent path.

How should I be setting these paths?  This is the output I'm getting:

```
Status of the individual requirements:        
    
✓ Java JDK                                    
✗ Android SDK: 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT' environment variable is set to non-existent path:
        /root/Android/Sdk
        Try update it manually to point to valid SDK directory.
✗ Android target: Command failed with EACCES: avdmanager list target
        spawn avdmanager EACCES
✓ Gradle
```

I have set the `JAVA_HOME` path to:

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the `Android` directory to `/etc` solved it:

```
sudo su
mv /root/Android /etc
```

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME should be something like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`

There are no sdks because you need to populate using or android studio or something like the sdkman command line utility

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).